# C++ copy constructor with pointers

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I understand the need to deep copy pointers (in cases when you want a complete copy of an object), my confusion comes with the following (completely made up example).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

class a
{
public:

    a::a(std::string _sz) : 
        m_sz(_sz)
        ,m_piRandom(new int)
    {
        *m_piRandom = 1;
    };

    ~a()
    {
        delete m_piRandom;
        m_piRandom = NULL;
    };

    a::a(const a &toCopy)
    {
        operator=(toCopy);
    }

    a& a::operator=(const a &toAssign)
    {
        if (this != &toAssign)
        {
            m_sz = toAssign.m_sz;
            if (m_piRandom)
            {
                // Need to free this memory! 
                delete m_piRandom;
                m_piRandom = NULL;
            }

            m_piRandom = new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void SetInt(int i)
    {
        if (!m_piRandom)
        {
            m_piRandom = new int;
        }
        *m_piRandom = i;
    }

private:

    std::string m_sz;
    int* m_piRandom;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    a Orig = a("Original");
    a New = a("New"); 
    New.SetInt(9);
    New = Orig;

    return 0;
}
```

Now in my example I want to test the scenario where I have an object with some memory allocated to it, in this case:

```
a New = a("New"); 
New.SetInt(9); // This new's the memory
```

allocates the memory and then when we say: `New = Orig;` I would expect a memory leak because if I blindly new'd the `m_piRandom = new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom);` I would have lost the memory it was previously pointing to..

So I decided to put the following in the assignment operator:

```
if (m_piRandom)
            {
                // Need to free this memory! 
                delete m_piRandom;
                m_piRandom = NULL;
            }
```

This crashes the code when the following is called (first line!) `a Orig = a("Original");` as it calls the copy constructor (which I call the assignment operator for less duplication) and the pointer `m_piRandom` is set to 0xcccccccc. Not NULL. Therefore it tries to delete memory that was never allocated. I would expect it to work when it got to the `New = Orig;` because it would delete it first before assigning the copy. Can anybody shed any light on this, I guess my biggest concern is that m_piRandom is not NULL, I also tried defining a default constructor for a which NULLs the pointer by default but this didn't help. Apologies for the completely contrived code..

Thanks

Comment: Note that `new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom)` allocates a *single* integer, and initializes it to `*toAssign.m_piRandom`.

Comment: As for your problem, you can't really use the exact same code for both the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator, as the semantics is, as you noticed, a little difference. However, you can work around it by simply initializing the pointer in the copy-constructor.

Comment: you surely mean `a::a(const a &toCopy) : m_piRandom(nullptr) { operator=(toCopy); }`.

Comment: Thanks guys I have made this change, there is nothing wrong with calling the assignment operator to save having to bother with all of the assignments is there, providing I always initialise the members in the initialiser list of the copy constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is that you implemented the copy constructor in terms of the assignment operator. The copy constructor brings a new object into existence based on some other object, whereas the assignment operator clears and changes the bits of an already created object.

So, your proper copy constructor would be:-

```
a::a(const a &toCopy) : m_sz(toCopy.m_sz), m_piRandom(new int)
{
    *m_piRandom = toCopy.m_piRandom;
}
```

After implementing this you can simplify your assignment operator:

```
a& a::operator=(const a &toAssign)
{
    if (this != &toAssign)
    {
        m_sz = toAssign.m_sz;
        if (m_piRandom)           //<<<<< No need to check this as it should always be
        {                         //<<<<< initialized by constructors.
            delete m_piRandom;    
            m_piRandom = NULL;
        }

        m_piRandom = new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

After removing these redundancies, your assignment operator looks like

```
a& a::operator=(const a &toAssign)
{
    if (this != &toAssign)
    {
        m_sz = toAssign.m_sz;
        m_piRandom = new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: The suggested assignment operator has a memory leak. I suggest using copy & swap for this.

Comment: Well that's the best option but I thought road to that goes from first having clear distinction between assignment/copy operations. That's why I just clarified problems in the code...Till that time our pretty destructor have to handle bit more responsibility.

Comment: Captain Obvious please can you explain how to remove the memory leak in the assignment operator without using copy & swap? Thanks

Comment: `int *tmp(new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom)); std::swap(m_piRandom, tmp); delete tmp;` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks or if not using std::swap (My company don't use std library, my example is for ease of understanding) I could just check for m_piRandom being NULL in the assignment and if it's NOT delete it before assigning, as per my original example?

Comment: _Sigh_ - without swap - `int *tmp(new int(*toAssign.m_piRandom)); delete m_piRandom; m_piRandom = tmp;`. Don't bother checking for `NULL`. `delete NULL;` results in a no-op and is defined in the standard.

Comment: Thank you. FYI I like to use std library stuff just can't in this environment. Good to know though. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because the copy constructor doesn't initialize `m_piRandom`. This means the variable will be (most probably) filled with garbage (whatever was at the memory location when initializing the object).

The call sequence is this:

```
a::a() [doesn not initialize m_piRandom] -> a::operator= -> delete m_piRandom.
```

To fix:

```
a::a(const a &toCopy)
: m_piRandom{ nullptr } // <---- add this
{
    operator=(toCopy);
}
```

**Edit**: you could improve the assignment operator drastically using [copy&swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-and-swap).

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is that your copy constructor does not initialize your int pointer membrer, but assignment operator assumes correct value for it. So simply initialize int pointer to 0 in copy constructor before calling assignment operator.